# How do you both align and resize an image CALayer?

Tags: cocoa, macos, layout, core-animation, calayer

I have a somewhat complicated requirement for layout of a few Core Animation layers. Basically, I have two layers, with CGImage contents, that need to resize (preserving their aspect ratios), but also cling next to each other in the middle of their parent layer. I've illustrated this below.

(Both of my illustrations show the bounds of Layer A's and Layer B's image contents. It doesn't matter if the layer itself is sized larger.)

[image: Desired Layout]

The closest I've come so far, using CAConstraintLayoutManager is to get them scaled properly, but centered in their half of the superlayer (below).

[image: Current, incorrect, layout]

I'm getting them to this point with the code below:

```
layerA.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
[layerA setConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMinX relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMinX],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxX relativeTo:@"superlayer" kcaConstraintMidX],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMinY relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMinY],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxY relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMaxY],
                        nil]];

layerB.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
[layerB setConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMinX relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMidX],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxX relativeTo:@"superlayer" kcaConstraintMaxX],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMinY relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMinY],
                        [CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxY relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMaxY],
                        nil]];
```

How can you resize two layers, and also align them?

One idea that occurred to me was to create a layer that contained A and B, laid out properly, with no margin around the edges, and then scale that. I can't figure out a way to do that, either, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still open to a better answer, but I made my own `CALayoutManager` subclass, which implements a custom `-layoutSublayersOfLayer` to place the sublayers' frames exactly where I want them. I also made a `+layoutManager` method so my custom layout manager can simply be swapped for the `CAConstraintLayoutManager`.